# Problem extracting specific value from a date column

Tags: python

I have a pandas data frame in python. Lets call it  *Data_set*. This data frame has a column of type **pandas.core.series.Series** which holds date information, one instance is  **2019-09-01 00:02:24.545000+00:00**. I am trying to figure out an automatic procedure in order to change this whole date into a single number. For example in the case  **2019-09-01 00:02:24.545000+00:00** I want to replace it with **09** (day). I tried to use the following command `datetime.strptime(strDate, '%m/%d/%y')` but it didn't work. Also, I tried the following for loop in order to change the whole date column

```
for k in range(Data_set.shape[0]):
    Data_set['strDate'][k]=Data_set['starDate'][k].split()[0] #for the first date (also first row) split it to components
    Data_set['strDate'][k]=Data_set['strDate'][k][5:7] # indices [5:7] which correspond to 09 (day)
```

but also it didn't work.

Comment: A couple of things pop out at me. First, you are using slashes in your strptime format, but the data has dashes. Second, I don't see any obvious problem with your code except for the typo "starDate". What error are you getting?

Comment: So I changed dashes to '-'. And I get this error ```strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series```

Comment: I usually fire up pdb at this point and start looking at variables in the interpreter.  You need to make sure the first parameter is a string, instead of whatever it is you're giving it.

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that I was using function that couldn't handle pandas variables. Thus what I did is I converted the date column to pandas date type with ```pd.to_datetime(Data_set['strDate']) ``` and then I used the dt.day function which is for pandas variables ```Date_set['strDate'].dt.day```.